# Scatter plot of >1 million points in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am using the using the code below to plot 3D data. When the number of points N>10,000 the performance slows down, both while showing the figure window and while interacting with the plot. Are there other modules which can handle large number of data points with better performance?.

I could sub-sample the data for some tasks, but I still have a need for this functionality.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
N = 100000
data = np.random.randn(N, 3)
x,y,z = data[:,0:3].T
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Data Shader](http://datashader.org/) from PyViz, their front-page example plots 300 million points "without any parameter tuning."